# Octave/Matlab - Cannot/plot data

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a simple data file looking like this:

```
data.txt
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
```

And I am trying to plot its data using the following code:

```
data = load('data.txt');
X = data(:, [1, 2]); y = data(:, 3);

plotData(X, y);

hold on;

xlabel('Exam 1 score')
ylabel('Exam 2 score')

legend('Admitted', 'Not admitted')
hold off;

pause;
```

However this bring me the following errors:

```
warning: legend: plot data is empty; setting key labels has no effect
error: legend: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
```

And nothing gets plotted.

I don't understand what's wrong. The working directory is fine in octave.

How can I fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you need to use cell arrays there - `legend({'Admitted', 'Not admitted'})`.

Comment: I tried but its still not working :(

Comment: what do you get when printing `X` and `y`? Are they really empty? Also, try using [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) instead of [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html). Load is for matlab variables stored in files.

Comment: `plotData` is not a standard octave function, look at that. Sub plot for it and it works.

Comment: You need to implement the function plotData in plotData.m
Read the document.

Comment: @Spearfisher this is the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36125516/1487781, please mark it as an answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) X is a 5x2 array while y is a 5x1 array

2) plotData isn't a Matlab command, use plot instead

Try the following code:

```
data = load('data.txt');
x1 = data(:, 1);
x2 = data(:,2);
y = data(:, 3);

plot(x1, y);
hold on
plot(x2,y);

xlabel('Exam 1 score')
ylabel('Exam 2 score')

legend('Admitted', 'Not admitted')
hold off;
pause;
```

Answer (score 10):

You are trying the assignment on week three in machine learning course by Andrew Ng on coursera. There in ex2.m file, there is a call to function plotData(X,y) which refers to the function written in plotData.m file. You may thought that plotData is a default function in octave, but you actually need to implement that function in plotData.m file. 
Here is my code in plotData.m file.

```
function plotData(X, y)
%PLOTDATA Plots the data points X and y into a new figure 
%   PLOTDATA(x,y) plots the data points with + for the positive examples
%   and o for the negative examples. X is assumed to be a Mx2 matrix.

% Create New Figure
figure; hold on;

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Plot the positive and negative examples on a
%               2D plot, using the option 'k+' for the positive
%               examples and 'ko' for the negative examples.
%

pos = find(y==1);
neg = find(y==0);
plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), 'k+','LineWidth', 2, ...
'MarkerSize', 7);
plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'y', ...
'MarkerSize', 7);

% =========================================================================



hold off;

end
```

Comment: Please consider this the accepted answer if this helps the most.

Answer (score 7):

If you read the pdf carefully, the PlotData.m codes are is in the pdf.
Here is the code:

```
% Find Indices of Positive and Negative Examples
pos = find(y==1); neg = find(y == 0);
% Plot Examples
plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), 'k+','LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 7);
plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'y','MarkerSize', 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% Find Indices of Positive and Negative Examples
pos = find(y==1); neg = find(y == 0);
% Plot Examples
plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), 'k+','LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 7);
plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'y','MarkerSize', 7);
```

You have to type the above code (not copy and paste) from the PDF document to the plotData.m file.